# Slider with progress bar that reach dots

Tags: jquery, slider, progress-bar

I'm searching google for few days. I'm looking for slider with progress bar that reach dots/points.

I've found something that interested me and could work:
[Presentation Cycle](http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/presentationCycle/)

but when you click the dot/point, the progress bar stops. I want it to be in constant motion.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by comment (remove) 3 lines in presentationCycle.js file:
Function on line 166.

```
gotoSlide: function(itemNr) {
//  $(presentationCycle.barContainerOverflow).stop();
//  presentationCycle.disableAnimation = true;
$('#' + presentationCycle.containerId).cycle((itemNr - 1));
// $('#' + presentationCycle.containerId).cycle('pause');
}
```